# Zero-initializing a `std::array` of arithmetic `value_type` at compile-time results in a missing constructor note

Tags: c++, constexpr, stdarray

To initialize an `std::array` of an arithmetic type `AT` at compile-time, I did this:

```
#include <array> 
#include <iostream>

template<typename AT, auto DIM, auto N = 0> 
constexpr void assign(std::array<AT, DIM>& arr, AT value)
{
    arr[N] = value; 
    if constexpr (N < std::size(arr) - 1)
        assign<AT, DIM, N + 1>(arr, value);
}

template<typename AT, auto DIM>
constexpr std::array<AT, DIM> zero_array() 
{
    std::array<AT, DIM> result;  
    assign(result, AT{0});
    return result;
}

template<typename Container> 
void print(Container&& cont)
{
    for (const auto& el : cont)
        std::cout << el << " "; 
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto zero10 = zero_array<double, 10>(); 
    print(zero10); 
}
```

I [godbolted it](https://godbolt.org/z/9IkURZ), and it seems to me it worked:

[image]

However, when I compile it with

```
g++  -O3 -std=c++2a -Wall -Wpedantic -Wunused-parameter -I /usr/include main.cpp -o main
```

using `g++ (GCC) 8.2.1 20181127`, I get a "note"

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘constexpr std::array<AT, DIM> zero_array() [with AT = double; auto DIM = 10]’:
main.cpp:30:42:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/8.2.1/array:94:12: note: ‘struct std::array<double, 10>’ has no user-provided default constructor
     struct array
            ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/8.2.1/array:110:56: note: and the implicitly-defined constructor does not initialize ‘double std::array<double, 10>::_M_elems [10]’
       typename _AT_Type::_Type                         _M_elems;
```

Why is this note there? Can I ignore it? If so, how to get rid of it?

Comment: `std::array` are aggregates, so `std::array<double, 10> zero10 = {};` will perform value initialization for missing members, which is 0-initialization for `double`.

Comment: BTW I think your assign function would explode when using zero-sized std::arrays (yeah they are legal!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::array` does not have a default constructor. You need to use:

```
std::array<AT, DIM> result = {};
```

What's puzzling to me is why you think you need `zero_array` at all. If you use

```
std::array<double, 10> a = {};
```

you get a zero-initialized object.

Comment: Thanks! :) I got puzzled by using something like `std::array<double, 10> zeroZero10; print(zeroZero10);` and getting garbage output : `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6.93865e-310 6.93865e-310 6.93865e-310`. Why isn't this construction also zero-initializing elements, if `{}` is doing that?

Comment: @tmaric Because for "Plain Old Data"-like types in C++, constructing with `{}` is different than constructiong with nothing.

Comment: @tmaric, I am not a language lawyer. I don't always understand the logic behind why a certain rule is in place. This is one of those.

Comment: @tmaric Because "you don't pay for what you don't use" (C++ "idiom"). This rules come from aggregate initialization rule in C, extended in C++. Especially, `double zeroZero10[10] = {}` would perform zero-initialization, so it's kind of logic that `std::array` have the same behavior. You can choose between an uninitialized structure (because you don't need one) and an initialized one, which is better than not being able to choose ;)

Comment: @Holt: OK! So it's not an inconsistency, it's an option. Thanks!